# MySQL: Select whole column but convert NULL to custom string

Tags: mysql

I looked for over 2 hours now and I can't get my problem solved with any of the code I found on the internet. I am new to MySQL and I am only using it in a script language based on Java.
In my script I want to set an array variable to the result of a mysql query which selects a whole column, BUT it should check at each row if it's NOT NULL = actual value and if it's NULL(not set), it should output a customizable string for only this row. (I only found possibilities to change the complete output of the query, but it should check one row after another and then give out the array where every NULL has been replaced with my custom string) 
I am using a mysql database with one table and 2 columns (1: unique: varchar, 2: longtext). I want to give out the values of the longtext column.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean "select ifnull(actualValue,'customString') as myValue from someTable"?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get? If `IFNULL()` isn't working for you, you're not explaining what you need clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)? In your `SELECT`, you can provide a default value for NULL values.

> The MySQL IFNULL function allows you to return an alternate value if an expression is NULL.

The quote is from [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/ifnull.php).

Comment: yes I already tried this and COALESCE() as well, I tried this: `"SELECT IFNULL(mycolumn, 'alternativestring') FROM mytable"` , but as I understood, this can only check if the whole query is noll or not, so as my column has not-null-values as well, it will not be null in general. I need a code, which checks step by step row by row if the value is NULL and if it is, in this row the value gets replaced with my string and added to the array.

Comment: @KenDerGuru Your understanding is wrong, it checks the value in each row. When the value is `NULL` it returns the alternate string, when it's not null it returns the actual value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works perfectly. That was the syntax I needed. That it didn't work after you answered was caused by a mistake in my script. Now everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: So I used this one from @Barmar  sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a03ffa/1.

Comment: @Barmar I feel apologetic that I got the acceptance vote, when you are the one who helped them more. If you want to make an answer please, I'll delete my answer, and he/she can accept your answer.

Comment: @Abdul I've got more reputation than I know what to do with, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce will return the first non null value.

Example:

```
select coalesce( theField, 'theCustomString') from theTable
```